# How to save large file with different file name (KDB)?

Tags: kdb

I have a somewhat large table(around 3GB when saved) in a variable called "data".

I can save it to a file with:

```
save `:data.csv
```

However, if I try to save it with a different filename, I get an error:

```
sd: 2017.12.08;

string[sd],".csv" set data

ERROR: 'limit 
(tried to generate a list with more than 2,000,000,000 elements (keep in mind that any IPC result is a byte list, hence can't be longer than 2 metric Gb))
```

How can I overcome this error? I tried a variety of methods, and I'm sure this is simple, but wasn't able to find a workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[set](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/get/#set) will save the table in binary format, not csv. Use [0:](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/file-text/#save-text) (which is used by `save` internally) to save the table in csv format with a different file name:

```q
q)hsym[`$string[sd],".csv"] 0: csv 0: data
`:2017.12.08.csv
```

Comment: Beautiful solution. Thank you, kind stranger!

Comment: Is there any way I can append a file path to this? Can't figure out how despite a bunch of attempts.

Comment: To answer my own comment - I was able to do: `hsym[\` sv \` :/path,\`$string[ed],".csv"] 0: csv 0: data; `

Comment: Other ways to do it: 1) string concatenation: ``hsym[`$"/path/",string[sd],".csv"] 0: csv 0: data`` 2) [.Q.dd](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qdd-join-symbols): ``.Q.dd[`:/path;`$string[sd],".csv"] 0: csv 0: data``

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get round the limit by writing to the file in batches rather than bulk. Below is a function that would allow you to do so. The function takes 3 parameters: batch sizes `n`, a filename `f` and `data` to be written to file. It opens a handle to the file, checks if the file is empty with `hcount` and writes column headers if necessary. Data is then saved in batches and the file handle closed on finish.

```
chunk:{[n;f;data]
  h:hopen f;                                   / open file handle
  if[0=hcount f;h","sv string cols data];      / write headers to empty file
  {x raze"\n",/:1_","0:y}[h]'[n cut data];     / write chunks to file
  :hclose h;                                   / close file handle
 };
```

This function is quite simplified as it does no checking of schema so may cause issues when mixed schemas are passed to it.